# How to find if inside or outside a OpenMP single block

Tags: c++, openmp

Some code must not run genuinely parallel: either not inside a OpenMP parallel region or within a OpenMP single block. How can I assert that the code is not running genuinely parallel (ignoring for the time being the complications arising from nested parallelism)?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you want.

However, you could use the "critical" construct to ensure a code section is executed only by one thread at a time, and then set some flag to prevent it to be run by another thread, if it should be run only once.

Comment: sorry, but this obviously doesn't answer my question. I would accept an answer that can unambigiously prove that there is no solution.